# yii2 basic multiple language

Tags: php, yii2, frameworks, yii2-basic-app

I need to make website with 2 languages in Yii2 basic framework, however, I researched tons of times on google and other search engines and I could only find yii2 advanced internalisation. I need for basic mode, please if you have source codes for yii2 basic multiple languages or if you know any link or video tutorial about yii2 basic internalisation, please kindly share with me, I would be greatly appriciated.

I am looking forward from hearing from you soon.

Comment: U can refer these videos for multi language 
1)[File base](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_qNMcJKoEK0)

2)[DB base](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-OKk83F-4zc)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The best tutorial is official documentation.** 
So, look [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-i18n.html)

In basic app, i18n implementation has not difference from advanced app.

At first, set up your main config adding following keys:

```
return [
    // set target language to be Russian
    'language' => 'ru-RU',

    // set source language to be English
    'sourceLanguage' => 'en-US',

    ......
];
```

After that, create new file `/messages/ru-RU/app.php` (for implementing translation for `ru-RU` language. If you target language will be `es-MX`, so, that will be `/messages/es-MX/app.php`

Now In this file, you can implement translation of your strings

```
<?php

/**
* Translation map for ru-RU
*/
return [
    'welcome' => 'Добро пожаловать',
    'log in' => 'Войти',
    'This is a string to translate!' => 'Это строка для перевода'
    //...
];
```

When your file is ready, just configure i18n component in your main config file like this:

```
'components' => [
    // ...
    'i18n' => [
        'translations' => [
            'app*' => [
                'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                //'basePath' => '@app/messages',
                //'sourceLanguage' => 'en-US',
                'fileMap' => [
                    'app' => 'app.php',
                    'app/error' => 'error.php',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

Finaly, you can show your strings using `echo \Yii::t('app', 'This is a string to translate!');` So, you'll see `This is a string to translate!` when your app in `en-US` language, and `Это строка для перевода` when app in `ru-RU`;

To change target language, just create a simple action, something like

```
public function actionChangeLang($local) 
{
    $available_locales = [
        'ru-RU',
        'en-US'
    ];    

    if (!in_array($local, $available_locales)) {
        throw new \yii\web\BadRequestHttpException();
    }

    \Yii::$app->language = $local;

    return $this->goBack();
}
```

Comment: thank you soovorow, and can you please explain me what is main config in basic one?

Comment: G'ulornjon, I mean the config file where you are configuring app components. I think for you that will be this file https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-basic/blob/master/config/web.php

Comment: by the way Soovorow, can you also show me how to check if my translation is worked or not? I mean I dont know the URL for how to switch the language from RU to EN

Comment: G'ulornjon, man, I put the sample action for changing language in my answer. Add it in your SiteController, and than you'll be able to change it by `/site/change-lang?local=ru-RU` url