# Yii2 framework: How to change English default language to Spanish

Tags: php, yii2, internationalization, yii2-advanced-app

I am using the Yii2 Framework and I am translating all texts of buttons, labels, messages, etc.

Then I read this article http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-i18n.html that shows how to do it automatically but I don't understand it.

I want to translate to Spanish from Argentina: **es-AR** or at least to any Spanish.

So I think I need to change from **en-US** to **es-AR** but I would like to know which files should I change.

Also I am using the great Gii code generator where I can see a checkbox called **Enable I18N**.

I watched these files but I am not sure if I am looking the right files:

- vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php
- vendor/yiisoft/yii2/i18n/I18N.php
- common/config/main-local.php

Answer (score 4):

Add `language` propery and `i18n` component in application config. For advanced application template in `common/config/main.php`

```
return [
    'language' => 'es-AR',
    ...
    'components' => [
        ...
        'i18n' => [
            'translations' => [
                'app*' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                    'basePath' => '@app/messages',
                ],
            ],
        ],
        ...
    ],
]
```

Use `Yii::t()` for all user messages (model labels, views, error messages etc).

```
echo \Yii::t('app', 'Friend');
```

Create directory `messages/es-AR`. Create file `app.php` in this directory and add translations

```
return [
    'Friend' => 'Amigo',
    'Girl' => 'Сhica',
    ...
];
```

Comment: Do you mean the file yii.php?  It exists in /vendor/yiisoft/yii2/messages/es.
Where should I write es-AR so Yii2 can translate to Spanish?

Comment: 'language' => 'es-AR' in common/config/main.php

Answer (score 1):

**Try to look into the official documentation, it is best tutorial for you**. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-i18n.html

Also, look at this answer [yii2 basic multiple language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45453805/yii2-basic-multiple-language/45454360#45454360)

You can change default language by changing `'language'` parameter of your main configuration file. Like this:
return

```
[
    // set target language to be English
    'language' => 'en-US',
]
```

Where instead `'en-US'`  you must to set needed locale code, e.g. `'es-AR'`